# using "bitwise and" operator c++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I have the following code

```
int n = 50;
while(n) {                         //1
    if(n & 1) cout << "1" << endl; //2 
    //right shift the number so n will become 0 eventually and the loop will terminate
    n >>= 1;                       //3
}
```

When we use bitwise and 1 (& 1) with a number we get back the same number.
Now my question is how does c++ evaluates the following expression: n & 1.
Since:

```
  n = 50
  In binary form 50 is:            110010
  If we bitwise 1 then we get:  AND     1 = 110010
  Now in c++ (2) the expression evaluates like this:
  Instead of getting the whole sequence of bits (110010) bitwise anded with 1    
  it evaluates only the number of right bits we bitwise. In my example:
  n=50, 110010, use n & 1 ==> 0 AND 1 instead of 110010 AND 1.
```

Is there a reason that c++ treats the bitwise and like this? My guess would be it has to do with the compiler ?

Comment: But remember that `1` is actually `00000001` in binary, and bitwise operations use *all* the bits.

Comment: The same BIT VALUE, single bit, not number (which in general is many bits), in "When we use bitwise and 1 (& 1) with a number we get back the same number"

Comment: oh now i see so when i use n & 1 i actually get this: 110010 AND 000001 ?

Comment: @KostasRim that's literally what it is saying, not some sort of "I wrote this but I actually get this other thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

> The bitwise AND operator is a single ampersand: &. It is just a representation of AND which does its work on the bits of the operands rather than the truth value of the operands. Bitwise binary AND does the logical AND (as shown in the table above) of the bits in each position of a number in its binary form.

In your example `110010` & `1`, `1` is considered as `000001`, and then each bit is `anded` and you get the result. In fact, I use this method: `1&number` to check for even and odd numbers. This is how:

```
if(1 & num)
  printf("it is odd");
else 
  printf("it is even");
```

This is how it works: suppose you have an 8 bit number. Now, the 8 bit notation of `1` will be `00000001`.

If I now perform `and` on each bit, for all the first seven bits I will get `0`, because it will be `0 & anything` will be 0. Now, the last bit of `1` is 1. So, if my number also has last bit as `1`, then `1 & 1 = 1`, and if my last bit is `0`, then `1 & 0 = 0`.

When will the last bit in my number be `1`? And when `0`? When converting to decimal form, the last bit is multiplied by 2<sup>0</sup>. And, 2<sup>0</sup> = 1. If this `1` is multiplied with 1, we get an odd number, and if it is multiplied with 0, we get an even number.

Answer (score 3):

> When we use bitwise and 1 (& 1) with a number we get back the same number.

No we don't. We get back the number consisting of the bits that are set in both the original number and in 1. Since only the lowest bit of 1 is set, the result is the lowest bit of the original number.

> Now my question is how does c++ evaluates the following expression: n & 1.

If `n` is 50, then in binary:

```
n:    110010
1:    000001
n&1:  000000 // no bits set in both
```

If `n` is 51, then in binary:

```
n:    110011
1:    000001
n&1:  000001 // one bit set in both
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i will mark it as solved.