# use of "&" operator in conditional statement in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main()
int n=5;
if(n & 1)
cout<<"odd";
else
cout<<"even";
```

how we are getting even or out using "&" operator
it should have been like this

if(n%2!=0) to check the even or odd.
can anyone explain what is that code doing.

Comment: Are you asking why that first one works, or why the second one is used when the first one exists?

Comment: It using the *bitwise and operator* to check if the lowerst bit of `n` is set (in other words if `n` is odd).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30165137/using-bitwise-and-operator-c ?

Comment: The first one uses bitwise and operator `&` on `n` with `1`. so if `n`'s LSB bit is set then `n` is odd otherwise even: `01101001001 & 00000001 = 1` odd. `01110101110 & 00000001 = 0` even.

Comment: @john Please do not answer in the comments section.

Comment: @Itachi Please do not answer in the comments section.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: hhhhhh why?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa A comment can't be marked as an accepted answer. Comments also bypass user moderation tools such as edits and voting.

Answer (score 0):

What "n & 1" does here is that it returns the bitwise AND between n and 1. In other words, this is checking whether the last bit of n is equal to 1.

If it is, then n is odd, because the least significant bit of all binary representations of odd numbers is 1. If it's not, then n is even, because the least significant bit of all binary representations of even numbers is 0.

Comment: thanks didnot know this logic...does it affect in space or run time complexity...I mean is it only just a way to write as ones need...?

Comment: @PraneshPrashar They are both O(1) in time and space, though there probably is some difference in performance which shouldn't be noticeable. Bitwise operations are usually faster, as they directly map to bitwise assembly instructions.